# Spring Boot - How to create a standalone authenthication MICROSERVICE?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I wrote my first backend spring boot application.

I also created a **seperate** frontend application.

I would like to create a standalone basic authentication microservice.
The authentication thechnology is currently not relevant. It can use JWT, OUTH2, OKTA, whatever.

I emphsize the MICROSERVICE, rather than adding classes to an application code.

This is because all that I could find on the web and in several books was adding this authentication part as an embedded code in a whole spring boot application.

I would like to build an authentication seperate **microservice**, such the my other microservices (currently I have only one SP, but there will be more), will be able to use it in order to authenticate the users.

I hope I explained myself right :)

Could you please give me pointer for the correct implementation, or some updated tutorial which can help me accomplish this task?

---

UPDATE:

I have found a really great and up to date tutorial:

https://dzone.com/articles/step-by-step-a-simple-spring-boot-microservices-ba

Enjoy!

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you need an authentication service, you could work on validating the token generated by the authentication microservice.

You could:

1. Return a token from your authentication microservice;
2. Create a token validation service in your main microservice

The link below shows how to implement the authentication application in a manner that it works like an authentication gateway through JWT:
https://medium.com/@mool.smreeti/microservices-with-spring-boot-authentication-with-jwt-and-spring-security-6e10155d9db0

Alternatively, you could add a 3rd party solution to be linked to Spring Security. For this option, something like the code bellow in application.yml should work:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          sts:
            provider: sts
            client-id: ${STS_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${STS_SECRET_ID}
            client-authentication-method: post
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
        provider:
          sts:
            token-uri: ${STS_URL}
```

In my opinion, both ways are valid. It depends on your context and scope.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the link

Comment: I must say that, although the medium article is exactly what I need, it is so full of hops from point to point, missing many steps inside, code can not be copied as it being displayed by images... If I didn't have the article repository at hand, I never could follow it. And it is also hard with the repository. Anyways, this is ofcourse not your fault :)